# Workaround for passing variadic arguments to lambda expression if compiler does not support it

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have two solutions, both work as I expect but the first one
works only with newer version of GCC (5.2.1 for sure) and the second one works in GCC >= 4.8.3. The problem is that at my work I unfortunately do not have access to newer version of GCC.

The first solution is basically what I wanted by the behavior and by the level of complexity. The second one also works but this is the ugliest thing I have ever written and to be honest I do not know if this is the correct code (but it works).

Ok, firstly I will describe the problem that I am facing:
I have a function called `logic()` here, which takes callable object to invoke some additional logic among other instructions. These instructions of course are not here, because they are not necessary, they are marked as `(X)`.

```
template <typename C>
void logic (C c) {
    // before callable actions (X)
    c ();
    // after callable actions (X)
}
```

What I want to do as the callable object is to set some `bool` value(s) using appropriate type(s) - `set_single()` function. For the example I will use some additional types:

```
struct P1 {};
struct P2 {};
struct P3 {};
```

Consider first solution:

```
namespace Solution1 {

template <typename T>
void set_single (bool c) {
    // use type T to set c value - details are not the case here.

    std::cout << "value = " << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << "P1 = " << std::is_same<T, P1>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "P2 = " << std::is_same<T, P2>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "P3 = " << std::is_same<T, P3>::value << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename K, typename... Ts, typename... Vs>
void set_single (bool t, bool k, Vs&&... args) {
    set_single<T> (t);
    set_single<K, Ts...> (k, std::forward<Vs> (args)...);
}

template <typename... Ts, typename... Args>
void set (Args&&... args) {
    static_assert (sizeof... (Ts) == sizeof... (Args), "");

    logic ([&] () {
        set_single<Ts...> (std::forward<Args> (args)...);
    });
}

}
```

`set()` function is a wrapper and it is public for the user, `set_single()` are implementation details so they are hidden (for simplicity they are not written in a class).

So, passing callable object to `logic()` function inside `set()` function I invoke `set_single()` function arbitrary number of times passing all the values with corresponding types that I need. So, for example, usage could be like this:

```
Solution1::set<P1, P2, P3> (true, false, true);
```

and this will use type `P1` to set true, type `P2` to set false and type `P3` to set true.

So, here we have a solution when your compiler does not support passing variadic arguments to lambda expression.

```
namespace Solution2 {

template <typename... Ts>
struct X {
    X () = default;
    X (Ts... t) : tup {std::make_tuple (t...)} {}
    std::tuple<Ts...> tup;
};

template <int...>
struct Ints {};

template <int N, int... Is>
struct Int_seq : Int_seq<N-1, N, Is...> {};

template <int... Is>
struct Int_seq<0, Is...> {
    using type = Ints<0, Is...>;
};

template <int... Is>
using Iseq = typename Int_seq<Is...>::type;

template <int I, typename... Args, typename... Types>
void set_single (Ints<I>, const std::tuple<Args...>& a, const std::tuple<Types...>& t) {
    std::cout << "value = " << std::get<I> (a) << std::endl;
    auto p1 = std::get<I> (t);
    auto p2 = std::get<I> (t);
    auto p3 = std::get<I> (t);
    std::cout << "P1 = " << std::is_same<P1, decltype (p1)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "P2 = " << std::is_same<P2, decltype (p2)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "P3 = " << std::is_same<P3, decltype (p3)>::value << std::endl;
}

template <int I, int K, int... Is, typename... Args, typename... Types>
void set_single (Ints<I, K, Is...>, const std::tuple<Args...>& a, const std::tuple<Types...>& t) {
    set_single (Ints<I> {}, a, t);
    set_single (Ints<K, Is...> {}, a, t);
}

template <typename... Ts, typename... Args>
void set (Args... args) {
    static_assert (sizeof... (Ts) == sizeof... (Args), "");

    X<Ts...> types {};
    X<Args...> arguments {args...};

    logic ([&types, &arguments] () {
        set_single (Iseq<std::tuple_size<decltype (arguments.tup)>::value-1> {}, arguments.tup, types.tup);
    });

}

}
```

I used type `Solution2::X` to store values and types. I tried to do some `std::bind()` stuff, but it was painful, so I used 
some integer sequence (which probably implementation is rather poor). Like I said, both solutions work but the second one is not so cool like the first one.

**Could any of you tell me if `Solution2` can be replaced by some kind of easier solution? I am pretty sure that some exists.**

And usage with output looks like:

```
Solution1::set<P1, P2, P3> (true, false, true);

value = 1
P1 = 1
P2 = 0
P3 = 0
value = 0
P1 = 0
P2 = 1
P3 = 0
value = 1
P1 = 0
P2 = 0
P3 = 1


Solution2::set<P1, P2, P3> (true, false, true);

value = 1
P1 = 1
P2 = 0
P3 = 0
value = 0
P1 = 0
P2 = 1
P3 = 0
value = 1
P1 = 0
P2 = 0
P3 = 1
```

Comment: "here we have a solution when your compiler does not support passing variadic arguments to lambda expression."  I am not sure what it is that isn't supported in this description.  Something about passing and variardic arguments and a lambda expression, but what *exactly* you are saying your compiler does not support is not clear.  Also, `X` seems like a pointless wrapper around `std::tuple`.  Third, you are creating uninitizlied instances of some `Ts...` for ... no good reason I can see?

Comment: @Yakk: OP states clearly IMO the gcc versions supported, and you can see from [Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/HREbsA) that gcc 4.8.1 doesn't support version1 (which is valid C++11).

Comment: @Yakk "Third, you are creating uninitizlied instances of some Ts... for ... no good reason I can see?" Because in `X<Ts...> types {};` I care only about types not values.

"Something about passing and variardic arguments and a lambda expression, but what exactly you are saying your compiler does not support is not clear." I should probably say that variadic arguments can not be captured by reference in lambda expression.

Comment: @ArturPyszczuk You might not care about it, but `X<Ts...> types{};` actually creates a tuple containing `Ts...` and constructs them.  If that construction is illegal, or has side effects, this seems like a really, really, bad idea.  All you use the `types` for is the type.  Replace `X<Ts...> arguments` with `std::tuple<Xs...> arguments`.  Define `template<class T> struct tag_t {using type=T;};` then `template<class...Ts> struct pack { using tuple=std::tuple<tag_t<Ts...>>;};` with no storage, use that for `types`.  Extract the element type instead of creating those dummy variables.

Comment: @Yakk Thank you for your suggestion, I will try to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some tagging to keep the given type, as they might not be default constructible.

I would implement that way:

```
#if 1 // Not in C++11 // make_index_sequence
#include <cstdint>

template <std::size_t...> struct index_sequence {};

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct make_index_sequence : make_index_sequence<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> {};

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct make_index_sequence<0u, Is...> : index_sequence<Is...> {};

#endif // make_index_sequence

#if 1 // Not in C++11 // tuple_element_t
template <std::size_t I, typename T>
using tuple_element_t = typename std::tuple_element<I, T>::type;
#endif

namespace Solution3 {

    template <typename T>
    struct bool_impl {
        using type = bool;
    };

    template <typename T>
    using bool_t = typename bool_impl<T>::type; // or simply using bool_t = bool

    template <typename T>
    void set_single (bool c) {
        // use type T to set c value - details are not the case here.

        std::cout << "value = " << c << std::endl;
        std::cout << "P1 = " << std::is_same<T, P1>::value << std::endl;
        std::cout << "P2 = " << std::is_same<T, P2>::value << std::endl;
        std::cout << "P3 = " << std::is_same<T, P3>::value << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename T> struct Tag {};

    template <typename T1, typename T2, std::size_t ... Is>
    void set_singles (Tag<T1>, T2 t, index_sequence<Is...>) {
        int dummy[] = {0, (set_single<tuple_element_t<Is, T1>>(std::get<Is>(t)), 0)...};
        static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable
    }

    template <typename... Ts>
    void set (bool_t<Ts>... args) {
        Tag<std::tuple<Ts...>> tag;
        auto bools = std::make_tuple(args...);
        auto seq = make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>();

        logic ([&]() {
            set_singles(tag, bools, seq);
        });
    }

}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/F7zZHH)

And a version simplified for up to date compiler

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3c907f655d3d704)